# How to give permissions to 90+ SQL Servers without tweaking in each of them?

Tags: sql-server, optimization, permissions, configuration

There are over 90+ MS SQL Servers (SQL Server 2005, 2008 and 2012). All in the same Windows domain (but physically all over the world).

How to give a domain user (administrative, or other) access/permissions to its instances and databases without tweaking (creating, configuring) users/accounts and permissions for such user (or group) in each of 90+ servers, (and even more) their instances and databases?

**Update** (in respnce to @JonSeigel comment):

I have the list of MS Windows server-machines (domain names, ip-addresses) in domain without any access to either machines, SQL and App Servers in domain (supposedly, SQL and app Servers use default or common conventions names).

So, I should request the access in the form of exhaustive detailed description of the smallest privileges/permissions  of what I need.

The usage of `BUILTIN\Administrators` group provided such easy access to SQL Servers of earlier versions -  2005 and 2000. This would have been the most convenient for me. But it is not the case with MS SQL Servers 2008 and 2012.

I need to describe what I need with the smallest necessary privileges necessary for administering (monitoring, tuning, optimizing) MS SQL Servers + app servers that use MS SQL Servers (sometimes they are not even on the same machine).

Never been in such a situation before that I should describe what I need without even having read access to what I need

Comment: Are you referring to not tweaking the account in AD or in each instance?

Comment: Assuming you can run using a high privileged account that has enough permissions over all the servers at the same time, you could do this a bunch of different ways (PowerShell, Windows app, `sqlcmd` + batch file, ...). Do you have a master list of servers and instance names?

Comment: @ShawnMelton. "in each"

Comment: @JonSeigel , replied in **Update** to my question

Comment: Control server is the level of permission needed to access most of the monitoring and tuning items, at least for instance level. I had a client do this to many before and working through it all was a pain to get needed access.